# How to make Python data store on local machine which is similar to Google Python datastore?

Tags: python

How to store data on local machine using Python (and it's libraries, extensions ...) to easily access data (in OOP manner) which is similar to [Google Python data store](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/) for App Engine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should define "similar" to get more accurate answers... but here's my first attempt: use [mongodb](http://www.mongodb.org/) in conjunction with [pymongo](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/index.html).

My answer is based on the idea that both Google's data store and mongodb are schemaless databases, and that mongodb uses BSON (Binary JSON), where the "O" stands for "Object".

EDIT: [Apparently](http://continuations.com/post/81410630/welcoming-10gens-mongodb-datastore) the very genesis of mongodb is based on an attempt to imitate the Google stack.

Does this help?

Answer (score 3):

What about installing appengine dev SDK and use it locally ? Its internally storing the data in an sqllite db, but the python usage is same.

Recommended only if you just want to mimic the appengine style usage.